# setOnClickListener not working for button in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to build a simple calculator app for android using kotlin. But `setOnClickListener` is not working while clicking the buttons.

MainActiviy.kt

```
package com.example.calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlin.math.log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var result:EditText
    private lateinit var newNumber:EditText
    private lateinit var displayOperation:TextView


    private var operand1:Double?=null
    private var operand2:Double=0.0
    private var pendingOperation ="="

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        result = findViewById(R.id.result)
        newNumber=findViewById(R.id.newNumber)
        displayOperation=findViewById(R.id.displayOperation)



        val button0:Button = findViewById(R.id.button0)
        val button1:Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        val button2:Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
        val button3:Button = findViewById(R.id.button3)
        val button5:Button = findViewById(R.id.button5)
        val button6:Button = findViewById(R.id.button6)
        val button4:Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)
        val button7:Button = findViewById(R.id.button7)
        val button8:Button = findViewById(R.id.button8)
        val button9:Button = findViewById(R.id.button9)
        val buttonDot:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonDot)


        val buttonEqual:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual)
        val buttonAdd:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd)
        val buttonSub:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSub)
        val buttonMul:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonMul)
        val buttonDiv:Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonDiv)


        val listener = View.OnClickListener { v->
            val b = v as Button
            newNumber.append(b.text)
        }

        button0.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button1.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button2.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button3.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button4.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button5.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button6.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button7.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button8.setOnClickListener { listener }
        button9.setOnClickListener { listener }
        buttonDot.setOnClickListener { listener }





    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newNumber" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="."
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="="
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonDot"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonEqual"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonEqual" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="/"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayOperation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/newNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|text|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Is it crashing? Are the `Button`s not responding? Something else?

Comment: You don't need to use listener. For example  button0.setOnClickListener {  newNumber.text="0"}

Comment: @MikeM. The app is working fine. But there is no response while clicking buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not setting any listener to the buttons, but you're defining new listeners that don't invoke any method

**This will work:**

```
button.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

**This will work too, but here you have 2 listeners: the original one invoked by another one:**

```
button.setOnClickListener{ listener.onClick(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to implement `View.OnClickListener` you just need to trigger your local `listener` on button click.
 e.g. for `button0` make it

`button0.setOnClickListener { listener.onClick(it) }`

Data binding can reduce the `findViewById` lines. My latest environment provides data binding for kotlin by default.

Answer (score 0):

> first of all, you don't need to use findViewById in Kotlin. You can use it directly using id you provide in xml.
>
> 1. Use click listener like below

```
button6.setOnClickListener(object :View.OnClickListener{
        // do button click
    })
```

> 2. For multiple button click you can implement View.OnClickListener in activity and use it like.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),View.OnClickListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
     button6.setOnClickListener = this
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.button6 -> {
               // do button click
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

> If you don't want to set setOnClickListener for every button you can use databinding for that as well. It reduce lots of code.